# I have a jquery problem when using $.noConflict in master page

Tags: .net, master-pages, jquery

I had tried this in single page. I worked. But I try this in master page (dotnet), didnt work.
Can u say that what about this problem.

============== aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.master.cs" Inherits="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="javascripts/jquery.min.js">
  </script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
  </script>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

============== bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.aspx.cs" Inherits="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function goster() {
        alert(jQuery("#TextBox1").val());
    }
  </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onBlur="goster();" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is your javascript file reference relative to the content page? Have you used something like firebug to debug the javascript?

Comment: @Hawxby, I have control this in Firefox and I see javascript file. But It didnt work any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Mahesh. Answer of this problem is;

in bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.aspx page

function goster() {
        alert(jQuery("#ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1").val());
    }